# Impose condition on BelongsTo in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

In the following code, `BelongsTo::make('Answer', 'answer', Alternative::class)->searchable()` returns millions of records.

I'd like to restric this field with a condition: It's ID must me within the ID's of `HasMany::make('Alternatives')`

**Question.php (Nova Resource)**:

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),
        CKEditor::make('Wording', 'wording')->alwaysShow(),
        Boolean::make('Verified', 'is_verified'),
        Select::make('Type')->options([
            'multiple_choice' => 'Multiple Choice',
            'right_or_wrong' => 'Right or Wrong'
        ]),
        Tags::make('Level')->type('level')->single(),
        Tags::make('Subjects')->type('topic'),
        HasMany::make('Alternatives'),
        BelongsTo::make('Answer', 'answer', Alternative::class)->searchable()
    ];
}
```

I mean: A question has many alternatives. A question has one answer. 
I'd like to list only the possible answers in this field. Which happens to be the ones listed on `HasMany::make('Alternatives'),`

Right now, `BelongsTo::make('Answer', 'answer', Alternative::class)->searchable()` searches the whole database. I'd like it to show only the relevant entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select::make()` can be used in this situation: It queries it a restriction (the matching foreign key - or any other where clause) and creates a select box with the results.

```
Select::make('Answer', 'answer_id')->options($alts->pluck('letter', 'id')),
```

Comment: This is an OK work around.  There must be a better way.  I don't know what it is though.